# Radio button doesn't get selected after a post back

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback

I have an item template within repeater:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" 
                   value="<%# GetAssetId((Guid) (Container.DataItem)) %>" 
                   name="AssetId" 
                   <%# SelectAsset((Guid) Container.DataItem) %> />

        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I have a method that compares ids and decides whether to check the radio button.

```
protected string SelectAsset(Guid uniqueId)
{
    if (uniqueId == GetSomeId()) 
        return "checked=\"checked\"";

    return string.Empty;
}
```

`SelectAsset` gets hit, but it doesn't select a radio button on a post back, but it does work if I just refresh the page. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer here: [How to display "selected radio button" after refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954265/how-to-display-selected-radio-button-after-refresh) says that it's not possible to achieve, is this really the case?

Thank you

**Update**

It appears that view state isn't available for simple controls if they don't have a runat attribute. I have solved this by using a custom GroupRadioButton control. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the reason for avoiding  the `RadioButton` control? Are you rebinding the Repeater on postbacks?

Comment: ... or rather the [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) formatted with ` RepeatLayout="UnorderedList"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a RadioButtonList:

**Page Code**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="IndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ID="RadioRepeater" runat="server" />

<asp:Label ID="SelectedRadioLabel" runat="server" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    /* example adds items manually 
        - you could iterate your datasource here as well */
    this.RadioRepeater.Items.Add(new ListItem("Foo"));
    this.RadioRepeater.Items.Add(new ListItem("Bar"));
    this.RadioRepeater.Items.Add(new ListItem("Baz"));

    this.RadioRepeater.SelectedIndex = this.RadioRepeater.Items.IndexOf(new ListItem("Bar"));
    this.RadioRepeater.DataBind();
}

protected void IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SelectedRadioLabel.Text = string.Format("Selected Item Text: {0}", this.RadioRepeater.SelectedItem.Text);
}
```

I assume you only need to select one item.

---

As described in the comments, it even works to access the `SelectedItem` in the `Page_Load`event handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // previous code omitted
    }
    else
    {
        string foo = this.RadioRepeater.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this approach, none of the items are selected after postback.

Comment: @NathanDeWitt Just re-tested with exact code copied from here: works as described.

Comment: I'm trying to access this.RadioRepeater.SelectedValue during a PostBack and getting a null value.

Comment: @NathanDeWitt In that case you should either turn off `AutoPostback` on the `RadioButtonList` (and submit the form manually) or access it in the according Event Handler. I'm not sure if you can fiddle with event bubbling to make it work like you are trying now.

Comment: @NathanDeWitt I now tried with the same code to get the `SelectedItem.Text` and it worked with the only modification being an `else` to the orginal `if`. If you still have a problem, you should post *your* code in a new question.

Comment: I suspect it's because I'm creating the repeater items dynamically. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating all your controls dynamically at run-time (directly from code), then things are a little different. Here is the code that I used:

**Page Code**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
        rbl.AutoPostBack = true;
        rbl.SelectedIndexChanged += rbl_SelectedIndexChanged;

        rbl.Items.Add("All");

        // generate your dynamic radio buttons here
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            rbl.Items.Add(string.Format("Dynamic{0}", i));
        }
        form1.Controls.Add(rbl);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rbl.SelectedValue = "All";
            PopulateTextBox(rbl.SelectedValue);
        }

    }

    void rbl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList foo = (RadioButtonList)sender;
        PopulateTextBox(foo.SelectedValue);
    }

    void PopulateTextBox(string selection)
    {
        TextBox box = new TextBox();
        box.Text = selection;
        form1.Controls.Add(box);
    }
```

Comment: Ahh ... so you are essentially re-creating your control every time. [Dynamic adding controls during OnLoad or OnInit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3732387/205233) (and linked there) may have more details on what needs to be considered.